# How do I make the box below move ( accordion )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Didn't really know how to explain my problem in the title, my question is how do I make it so when I press the top box the other two boxes move down so you can see the text? The same goes for the other two boxes, if I press the middle the last box moves and when I press the last one the top and the middle stays. Plus the boxes has to go back to it's original place. Please I need help with this

```js
$(".faq,.faq2,.faq3").click(function() {
  $(this).find(".faq-box-more").toggleClass("open");

  $(".faq,.faq2,.faq3").not(this).find(".faq-box-more").removeClass("open");
});
```

```css
.faq,
.faq2,
.faq3 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}

.faq-box {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.faq-box h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-size: 1.9rem;
}

.faq-box i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 96%;
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 3rem;
  transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
}

.faq-box-more {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0%;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

.faq-box-more p {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.open {
  height: 140% !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section>
  <div class="faq">
    <div class="faq-box">
      <h2>lorem ipsum</h2>
      <i class="ion-ios-arrow-down"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="faq-box-more">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur numquam, atque nemo pariatur maiores eos harum, ab magni nisi quod, commodi ipsum totam vel nihil voluptatum vitae quisquam, qui amet!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="faq2">
    <div class="faq-box">
      <h2>lorem ipsum</h2>
      <i class="ion-ios-arrow-down"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="faq-box-more">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur numquam, atque nemo pariatur maiores eos harum, ab magni nisi quod, commodi ipsum totam vel nihil voluptatum vitae quisquam, qui amet!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="faq3">
    <div class="faq-box">
      <h2>lorem ipsum</h2>
      <i class="ion-ios-arrow-down"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="faq-box-more">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur numquam, atque nemo pariatur maiores eos harum, ab magni nisi quod, commodi ipsum totam vel nihil voluptatum vitae quisquam, qui amet!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I guess you are talking about accordion right? show content panel on click header.

Comment: check my answer below for explanation to how the accordion actually works. might help you in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see snippet below or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kh5vefyy/)

if you don't want to use the jqueryUI accordion and want to learn how it actually works, it's something like this

in CSS do not use absolute positioning on `faq-box-more` as it won't occupy any space. instead hide it with `display:none`

for JQ

first, you don't need to add different classes to all the `faq` divs, you can add one common class and then select the respective `faq-box-more` connected to the faq you click on , using jQuery methods below

when you click on `faq-box` ( either one of them ) , in a variable ( for cleaner and concise code ) you store the corresponding `faq-box-more` . 
you do this by using [`sibling()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method. searching `.faq-box`'s ' brothers ' for the `.faq-box-more` . in HTML structure `faq-box` and `faq-box-more` are on the same level, therefore they are siblings

then using an if condition you check if the previous selected `faq-box-more` is visible or not. IF YES -> close it , IF NO -> open IT .

you close and open using [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) and [`slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) methods ( click on the methods to see more info about them )

then, you also want to find any previous opened `faq-box-more` and close them, so only one is opened at one time ( the one corresponding to the box you clicked on ) . to do this you use the [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) method to 'climb' up the HTML structure and get to `faq` and then using `siblings()` and `find()` you find the `.faq-box-more` , and if it is open, you hide it with `slideUp()`

i think it's important that you try to understand the process behind the `accordion` and not just copy-paste it .

if you have anymore questions on this subject, feel free to ask in the comments

P.S. you had many problems in your code ( CSS ), it tried to correct some of them but also i wanted not to change too much your code.

```js
$(".faq-box").on("click",function() {
  var boxMore =  $(this).siblings(".faq-box-more")
   if ($(boxMore).is(":visible")) {
   $(boxMore).slideUp()
 } else {
  $(boxMore).slideDown(500)
 }


  $(this).parents(".faq").siblings().find(".faq-box-more").slideUp()
});
```

```css
.faq {
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}

.faq-box {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.faq-box h2 {



  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-size: 1.9rem;
}

.faq-box i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 96%;
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 3rem;
  transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
}

.faq-box-more {
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
 height:200px;
 display:none;
}

.faq-box-more p {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="faq">
    <div class="faq-box">
      <h2>lorem ipsum</h2>
      <i class="ion-ios-arrow-down"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="faq-box-more">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur numquam, atque nemo pariatur maiores eos harum, ab magni nisi quod, commodi ipsum totam vel nihil voluptatum vitae quisquam, qui amet!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="faq">
    <div class="faq-box">
      <h2>lorem ipsum</h2>
      <i class="ion-ios-arrow-down"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="faq-box-more">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur numquam, atque nemo pariatur maiores eos harum, ab magni nisi quod, commodi ipsum totam vel nihil voluptatum vitae quisquam, qui amet!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="faq">
    <div class="faq-box">
      <h2>lorem ipsum</h2>
      <i class="ion-ios-arrow-down"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="faq-box-more">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur numquam, atque nemo pariatur maiores eos harum, ab magni nisi quod, commodi ipsum totam vel nihil voluptatum vitae quisquam, qui amet!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```